# pass multiple textbox box values to controller in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I want to send multiple textbox values to CodeIgniter ..  I dont know why this code is not working ..

here is my view

```
 <th>Items:</th>
 <th>Price:</th>
 <th>quantity:</th>
 <th>total:</th>
    </tr>

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++) {?>
    <tr>
<td><?php echo form_dropdown('cat_id[]', $records2, '#', 
         "id='category_".$i."'     onchange='getItems(this.value,".$i.")' ");?>
                        </td>
     <!-- Items -->

  <td> <?php echo form_dropdown('item_id[]', $records3, '#', "id='items_".$i."'"); ?>

    </td>
```

the items dropdown options are coming against the category .. means if i select some thing from category then items will display against to that category

```
  <td><input type="text" name =<?php echo $price;?> id = "price_"<?php echo $i ?>>
</td>

<td><input type="text" name =<?php echo quantity;?> id = "price_"<?php echo $i ?>
```

i have set the field name of price and quantity to 'price' and 'quantity'

here is my controller..

```
$data3 = array(

            'item_id' => $this->input->post('item_id'),
            'price' => $this->input->post('price'),
            'quantity' => $this->input->post('quantity'),




    ); 

    $data4 = array();
    for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    {
        $data4 = array (

                'item_id' => $data3['item_id'][$i],
                'price' => $data3['price'][$i],
                'quantity' => $data3['quantity'][$i],

        );
    }

    $this->load->model('salesModel');
    $this->salesModel->addSoldItemtoDB($data4);
```

the problem is price value "null " is going into the database  and same for the quantity and as far as item_id concern whatever i select in item it is saving id  '1' in database..

my java-script for functionality of two drop down boxes above . categories and items

```
    <script type="text/javascript">

function getItems(category_id,index) {

       $("#items_" + index + " > option").remove(); 

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "stockInController/get_Items/"+category_id, 
        success: function(items) 
        {
            $.each(items,function(item_id,item_name) 
            {
                var opt = $('<option />'); 
                opt.val(item_id);
                opt.text(item_name);
                $('#items_'+ index).append(opt); 
            });
        }

    });
}
  </script>
```

Comment: what is the use of loop in your first dropdown? it is cause of problem

Comment: @raheel shan..because i am creating five rows similar to that

Answer (score 0):

You are creating text boxes with the same name

```
<input type="text" name =<?php echo $price;?> id = "price_<?php echo $i ?>" >
<input type="text" name =<?php echo quantity;?> id = "price_<?php echo $i ?>" >
```

Which means it will only take the last row's text boxes values. It should have been like this

```
<input type="text" name="prince_<?php echo $i;?>" id="price_<?php echo $i ?>" >
<input type="text" name="quantity_<?php echo $i;?>" id="quantity_<?php echo$i?>">
```

The other way is that create array in text boxes

```
<input type="text" name="price[]" id = "price_<?php echo $i ?>" >
<input type="text" name="quantity[]" id = "quantity_<?php echo $i ?>" >
```

And when you want to get values of these arrays.

```
$prices = $this->input->post('price');    
$quantity= $this->input->post('quantity');
```

Where prices and quantity are arrays

Comment: same think ..didnt work.. the price is going 0 in the database and the id of item is going 1